# Automatically add decorator to all inherited methods

Tags: python, inheritance, decorator, functools, setattr

I want in class B to automatically add the decorator _preCheck to all methods that have been inherited from class A. In the example b.double(5) is correctly called with the wrapper. I want to avoid to manually re-declare (override) the inherited methods in B but instead, automatically decorate them, so that on the call to b.add(1,2) also _preCheck wrapper is called.
Side note:

- I need to have a reference to the Instance of B in the wrapper (in my example via self)
- I want to avoid editing the Base class A.
- If possible, I want to encapsulate the decoration mechanism and initialization of it in the derived class B

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    
    def add(self, a, b):
        return a + b

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, name, foo):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.foo = foo
        
    def _preCheck(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs) :
            print("preProcess", self.name)
            return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
                
    @_preCheck
    def double(self, i):
        return i * 2
    
b = B('myInst', 'bar')
print(b.double(5))
print(b.add(1,2))
```

Based on [How can I decorate all inherited methods in a subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55013817/how-can-i-decorate-all-inherited-methods-in-a-subclass)
I thought a possible solutions might be to ad the following snippet into B's **init** method:

```
        for attr_name in A.__dict__:
            attr = getattr(self, attr_name)
            if callable(attr):
                setattr(self, attr_name, self._preCheck(attr))
```

However, I get the following error. I suspect the 2nd argument comes from the 'self'. .

```
TypeError: _preCheck() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

There exist solutions to similar problems where they either initialize the subclasses from within the base class :
[Add decorator to a method from inherited class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50366434/add-decorator-to-a-method-from-inherited-class)
[Apply a python decorator to all inheriting classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35624872/apply-a-python-decorator-to-all-inheriting-classes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decorators need to be added the class itself not the instance:

```
from functools import wraps

class A(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    
    def add(self, a, b):
        return a + b

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, name, foo):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.foo = foo
        
    def _preCheck(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs) :
            print("preProcess", self.name)
            return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
                
    @_preCheck
    def double(self, i):
        return i * 2

for attr_name in A.__dict__:
    if attr_name.startswith('__'): # skip magic methods
        continue
    print(f"Decorating: {attr_name}")
    attr = getattr(A, attr_name)
    if callable(attr):
        setattr(A, attr_name, B._preCheck(attr))
    
b = B('myInst', 'bar')
print(b.double(5))
print(b.add(1,2))
```

Out:

```
Decorating: add
preProcess myInst
10
preProcess myInst
3
```

Comment: Thanks you, that works great. Is there a way to encapsulate and execute this " decoration-loop" inside of class B, or would you suggest to include it in the class's file (without the instantiation)?

Comment: Add it to the class's file

Comment: I could actually do it in the def __new__ via the cls argument or is there a reason not to do it there (e.g. bad practice). I assume it will "unnecessarily" invoked for each instance that is created of B.

Comment: Yes, same for `__init__`.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative method, you could use a `metaclass` to override `A`s methods in `B` rather than modifying `A` itself.

```py
from functools import wraps

# move the decorator out of the class in order to use it in the metaclass
def _preCheck(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs) :
        print("preProcess", self.name)
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


class MetaParentDecorator(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        # iterate through base methods and create 
        # a decorated copy for the subclass
        for base in bases:
            for k, v in base.__dict__.items():
                if callable(v) and not k.startswith('__'):
                    print(f"Decorating: {k}")
                    dct[k] = _preCheck(v)
        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)


class A(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    
    def add(self, a, b):
        return a + b


class B(A, metaclass=MetaParentDecorator):
    def __init__(self, name, foo):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.foo = foo
                
    @_preCheck
    def double(self, i):
        return i * 2


b = B('myInst', 'bar')
print(b.double(5))
print(b.add(1, 2))
```

Results in:

```
Decorating: add
preProcess myInst
10
preProcess myInst
3
```

If you're unfamiliar with `metaclass`es, the simplest explanation is that they're responsible for creating your `class`. Typically, this is done by `type`, which is why you need to subclass `type`.

This has a few benefits:

1. It can be reused for other `class`es.
2. It leaves the base `class`
   unchanged, whereas the other version will directly modify `A`.
3. Since
   your `class` is only ever created once, `__new__` will only ever run
   once.

It does have drawbacks though, such as it being a lesser used part of Python so users of your code may be unfamiliar with it.

Comment: Thank you, that also looks also an elegant solution.